# Shell command to return value in json output

Tags: shell, aws-cloudformation

How to return a particular value using shell command?
In the following example I would like to query to return the value of "StackStatus" which is "CREATE_COMPLETE"

Here is the command:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stackname
```

Here is the output:

```
{
        "Stacks": [{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:64560756805470:stack/stackname/8c8e3330-9f35-1er6-902e-50fae94f3fs42",
            "Description": "Creates base IAM roles and policies for platform management",
            "Parameters": [{
                "ParameterValue": "64560756805470",
                "ParameterKey": "PlatformManagementAccount"
            }],
            "Tags": [],

            "CreationTime": "2016-10-31T06:45:02.305Z",
            "Capabilities": [
                "CAPABILITY_IAM"
            ],
            "StackName": "stackname",
            "NotificationARNs": [],
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "DisableRollback": false
        }]
    }
```

Comment: If you want: _return the value of "StackStatus" which is "CREATE_COMPLETE"_, **then** the value of the StackStatus will be `CREATE_COMPLETE`... Isn't?

Comment: How to return the value of "StackStatus" using shell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aws cli supports the *--query* option to get parts. In addition you could also pipe to another command line tool, *jq* to do similar query.

But in aws notation to get the 1st result:

`aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stackname --query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus' --output text`

Based on the above output, *Stacks* is an array of objects (a key/value), so hence need the *[0]* to get the 1st element of the array, and then *.StackStatus* is a key in this object containing a string as value.  The *--output text* simply presents the output as simple text value instead of a json-looking object.

*Edited per Charles comment.*

Comment: Good answer. That said -- and granted, this is unlikely -- if you had a file named `Stacks0.StackStatus` in the current directory where this was run, the argument `Stacks[0].StackStatus` would be interpreted as a glob and replaced with that name. Less unlikely, if no such file existed and you had the `failglob` option set, the shell would abort instead of executing the command at all; or with `nullglob`, that argument would be silently removed from the command line. In either case, the right answer is to quote the expression: `--query 'Stacks[0].StackStatus'`

Comment: good point! Always best to quote shell-specifics; I forgot that in my haste.